# mean.io, init: is an unrecognised token

Tags: mean.io

I have installed mean.io as per the documentation, on mac. However when I try to mean init myApp, I am presented with 'init:  is an unrecognised token!'. I have cleared my bower and npm caches as well as updated bower, npm, and gulp.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly enough, 'mean' was already pointing to a command in another library which I do not use often enough to have made the connection, initially.